# How to upload and download Images in to spark?

Tags: java, image, spark-java

How can I upload and download images with [spark](http://sparkjava.com/) as our web layer?

I found [this](http://deniz.dizman.org/file-uploads-using-spark-java-micro-framework/) example but it heavily relies on Jetty being the container and does not work for Tomcat.

Would love to see a full example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a standard servlet with built in functionality?

Sample Spark Servlet [Here](https://github.com/simonrice/SparkServletExample)

Sample Java Code [Here](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/eclipse-file-upload-servlet-with-apache-common-file-upload)